# Universal Algebra: an application of a Maltsev's algorithm to characterize congruences

Tags: universal-algebra, congruence-relations

In "Universal Algebra: Foundamentals and Selected Topics (pg. 107)" of Clifford Bergman the following Maltsev's theorem is intoduced for constructing congruences.

> Let $\textbf{A}$ be an algebra and $\theta \subseteq A^2$. The congruence generated by $\theta$ is equal to the set of all pairs $(a, b)$ such that:
> \begin{gather*}
> \exists z_0, \dots,z_n \ \ \ \ \exists(x_0, y_0), \dots,(x_{n-1}, y_{n-1}) \in \theta \ \ \ \ \exists f_0,\dots, f_{n-1} \in F^*_{(A)}
> \end{gather*}
> such that
> \begin{gather*}
> a=z_0, b=z_n \\
> \{z_i, z_{i+1}\}=\{f_i(x_i), f_i(y_i)\} \ \ \text{for} \ i<n
> \end{gather*}

Where $F^*_{(A)}$ is the monoid under the operation of composition generated by $F_{(A)}$, which is the set of elementary traslation of $\textbf{A}$. Here an illustration of how it works:

[image]

Then, to give an example, it is applied to characterize the principal congruences of a commutative ring with idendity $\textbf{R}$. In that case we have
\begin{gather*}
F^*_{(R)}=F_{(R)}=\{ax+b:a,b \in R\}
\end{gather*}
He wants to prove that the congruence generated by $(c, d)$ is $\{(rc+s, rd+s):r,s \in R \}$, showing that every step of the sequence $z_0, z_1, \dots, z_n$ collapses. For induction is sufficient showing that for $n=3$:
\begin{align*} 
z_0=r_0c+s_0 \\
z_1=r_0d+s_0 = r_1c + s_1 \\
z_2=r_1d + s_1\\
\end{align*}

Here the book conclude with the following passages:

> Then $s_0=r_1c +s_1 -r_0d$ so that $z_0=(r_0+r_1)c + (s_1-r_0d)$ while $z_2=(r_0+r_1)d + (s_1-r_0d)$

That, if they're right, concludes the demonstration but I can't get the last step, namely the expression for $z_2$. Surely I'm missing some easy steps, might you explain me how it is obtained? Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean the last expression for $z_2$? If so, based on $z_2 = r_1d+s_1$, it's only a matter of summing and subtracting $r_0d$.

Comment: Thank you! It was just that, if you post it as an answer I'll be glad to accept it. However I have other questions about this Maltsev's algorithm, so this post wil hopefully work also as a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that $z_2 = r_1d + s_1$, by summing and subtracting $r_0d$, we get
$$z_2 = r_0d + r_1d + s_1d -r_0d = (r_0 + r_1)d + (s_1 -r_0d).$$